# Como mudar uma loja de domínio?

Tags: magento

Preciso mudar minha loja na plataforma Magento de domínio, como devo proceder?

[LOJA AQUI](http://ffsolucoesweb.com/rvip/magento/)

Answer (score 2):

1) Em primeiro lugar, fazer a reconfiguração de conexão da aplicação com a base de dados. Isso foi feito alterando os valores do arquivo local.xml que está em: app/etc/local.xml;

2) Depois, como a instalação aponta para a URL diferente da minha “http://sualoja.teste/magento”, é necessário ir na base de dados e alterar os 2 registros da tabela CORE_CONFIG_DATA para a nova localização, no meu caso, para sualoja.teste.br… basta visualizar a tabela que é bem evidente quais registros devem ser alterados (se alguém não achar, os valores do campo “path” da tabela são, respectivamente: web/unsecure/base_url e web/secure/base_url);

3) Por último, o magento recupera os valores do cache antigo… então vá na pasta var/cache e apague sem dó os diretórios internos.

Comment: fiz as etapas, ele ta acessando a home, mas o admin não entra! o que devo fazer?

Comment: colocouo magento em qual url ? limpou o cache

Comment: http://rvipsuplements.com.br/

acessa ae

Comment: agora o problema é outro claro ... solução nesse link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18696/transferring-magento-website-admin-panel-url-gives-404

Comment: não consegui resolver, não tem aquele arquivo que ele manda deletar

Comment: pode me ajudar?

Comment: @Furlan abra uma nova pergunta com o novo erro, daí fica claro e tanto o Otto como qualquer outro usuário poderão lhe ajudar

Comment: valew @Caputo ! obrigado